# Ok to use newer (or both) libstdc++ on 32-bit Centos 6?

Tags: gcc, libstdc++

Our legacy product ships on 32-bit Centos 6.6, which has gcc 4.4.7 built in. However, the large app sometimes crashes from glibc corruption. Recompiling with gcc 4.8 and [AddressSanitizer finds "global-buffer-overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777835/understanding-addresssanitizer-global-buffer-overflow-error) and then crashes. However, compiling with gcc 4.9 seems to fix things: no glibc corruption and no AddressSanitizer errors.

The problem is the the app now requires `libstdc++.so.6.0.20` and no longer works with the stock Centos 6 `libstdc++.so.6.0.13` (`GLIBCXX_blahblah` not found, etc)

So what's the best approach?

1. Replace the stock `/usr/lib/libstdc++` with the new one?
2. Package the new `libstdc++.so.6.0.20` with our app (in a private directory) and modify `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` to load the private/new library before the system copies.

In #1, the file is owned by another package, so might again be overwritten by some future update. Also, would existing programs break if the `/usr/lib` version was updated?  I read a lot on ABI compatibility but it is a complex subject.

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to get minor interaction with other software.

**So, avoid replacing the stock version of the library.**

Moreover, there would also be possibly interractions with other software using /etc/ld.so.conf.

**So, the best way to avoid any interaction with other sotfware is to:**

- either **statically link** your libstdc++ 6.0.20 to your legacy product or app (you need the sources, or at least the independent objects files, to do that, so it may not be possible);
- or install libstdc++.so.6.0.20 in a specific directory, like /usr/local/my-own-version-for-my-app/lib, and instead of publishing this directory with ld.so.conf, use :

  - a **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** env var set to /usr/local/my-own-version-for-my-app/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH, just before launching your app:
  - or set the **LD_PRELOAD** env var this way: LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/my-own-version-for-my-app/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20, just before launching your app.

This means writting:

```
% export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/my-own-version-for-my-app/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
% ./launch_my_app
```

or:

```
% export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/my-own-version-for-my-app/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
% ./launch_my_app
```

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thanks!